# Android- Download from url Http redirect to html

Tags: android, http, redirect, download

I'm trying to download an epub from hosting, but the link I have is in HTTP, and I just download the html that redirects me, as I can download the original file?

This is my Download Code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://st10.file.karelia.ru/25nv8s/9789d242bd127ce31991dd68fa434caa/7958c0b30a9fa22938770ac65e9f2544/principito.epub");
URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
conexion.connect();
```

I Just download a html file, but when I use for example a Link from drop-box begin as https://, everything works.

Comment: Please ask question in english language only.

Comment: @Lucifer Sorry, I'm always wrong with that

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
URL url = new URL("http://st12.file.karelia.ru/25nv8s/598577e8b5897f89c7e44edb0b2f09aa/6d2b030e8c28b800e957af40960b8d46/20mil_leguas.epub?force");
URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
conexion.connect();
```